# Event for one Treeview item in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview, ttk

Tell me please, can I hang an event on one Treeview element? I know what you can do so:

```
def callback_view(event):
    print('123')

treeview.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', callback_view)
```

This function will work for all Treeview elements, but how to do that for one particular?

Comment: You'll have to add a test against the selected value. If you want more specific help please show us a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, you _can_.